# List of Figures and List of Tables do not show fancyhdr

Tags: table-of-contents, fancyhdr, incompatibility

I'm currently writing my Bachelor's Thesis and have already used LateX for several documents and reports so far. However, I cam across a problem during formatting my thesis. Throughout my whole work I want to use fancyhdr which gives me a horizontal line in the header of each page with the page numbering on the right upper corner (my thesis will be printed onesided).
Everything works fine besides the page numbering of my LOF and LOT. There the page numbering is on the bottom page in the middle (the default setting I think). After those two pages the page numbering is according to my wishes again.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{\thepage}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Figures}
\newpage
\listoftables
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Tables}
\newpage
```

What could possibly be the problem?

Comment: `\tableofcontents` and `\listof...` use `empty` or `plain` pagestyle sometimes, depending on the class. Using KOMA and `titlesec` is not a very good idea, neither is `fancyhdr` with KOMA, since the KOMA classes provides its own means for headers etc.  And please post fully working examples, not just fragments

Comment: Thank you, I'm still new to this forum, next time I'll give a better example. But what is an alternative to using fancyhdr with KOMA when I still want the horizontal line thorughout my document??

Comment: @mypsilon: See the KOMA manual, especially the chapter about `scrlayer-scrpage` package

Comment: @ChristianHupfer neither is tocloft. There are many options, one of them: `listof=totoc` to get the lof and lot to the toc, with the *right* page number. Package `tocloft` will destroy that. Without the package, there is no need to call newpage as well.

Comment: @Johannes_B: Yes, I forgot to mention `tocloft`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not recommanded to use `titlesec`, `tocloft` or `fancyhdr` together with a `KOMA-Script class`. Here is a suggestion using `scrlayer-scrpage`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,
  listof=totoc% <- added
]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[headsepline,manualmark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead{\pagemark}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\listoffigures
\clearpage
\listoftables
\clearpage
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

---

Note that package `tocloft` destroys the features of option `listof`. Additionally you have to define a matching `plain` style:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[headsepline,plainheadsepline,manualmark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead*{\pagemark}

\usepackage{tocloft}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Figures}
\listoffigures
\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Figures}
\listoftables
\clearpage
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Or you have to set `\tocloftpagestyle{scrheadings}`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[headsepline,manualmark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead{\pagemark}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\tocloftpagestyle{scrheadings}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Figures}
\listoffigures
\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Figures}
\listoftables
\clearpage
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: `tocloft` kills the `listof` mechanism, since `tocbasic` is no longer in charge. Can you add this to the answer?

Comment: @Johannes_B Done

Comment: I removed the packages that were not compatible with KOMA script (such as tocloft) and now it works just like I wanted, thank you!